# Inserting an array into sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
create proc InsertTagsForArticle(@ArticleID int, @TagIDsList nvarchar(max))
as
--...........
```

The parameter `@TagsList` contains  IDs of tags separated by comma: `"18,22, 23"`.
How to insert these IDs into table by more rational way?

EDIT: The question is how to **insert** an array into sql server table, but not how to parse an array. It's something like `foreach` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SQL server doesn't support native arrays, there's not much that you can do.

- Serialize this array and store in a field.
- Create child table / relations and store individual records there.

Your requirements will dictate what's better for you. But usually normalized approach is working better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use e.g. a user-defined function that splits the comma-separated string into a table - see e.g. here:

[SQL Server Helper - Comma-Delimited Value to Table](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/comma-delimited-to-table.aspx)

or **many** more available on the interwegs - just Google or Bing for "split comma-separated string into table" and you'll have thousands of hits....